# Newton-Raphson- proving a recurrence relation

Tags: numerical-methods

$$\def\ut#1{\underline{\text{#1}}}\def\vec#1{\mathbf{#1}} \def \d{\mathrm{d}} \def \p{\partial } \def \[{\left[} \def \]{\right]} \def \({\left(} \def \){\right)} \def \n{\boldsymbol{ \nabla}} \def\ut#1{\underline{\text{#1}}}\def\vec#1{\mathbf{#1}} \def\o#1{\operatorname{#1}} \def \{{\left\{} \def \}{\right\}} \def\hs#1{\enclose{horizontalstrike}{#1}} \def\vs#1{\enclose{verticalstrike}{#1}} \def \ba{\begin{align}} \def \ea{\end{align}} \def \bm{\begin{matrix}} \def \em{\end{matrix}} \def \bb{\begin{bmatrix}} \def \eb{\end{bmatrix}} \def \bv{\begin{vmatrix}} \def \ev{\end{vmatrix}} \def \bp{\begin{pmatrix}} \def \ep{\end{pmatrix}} \def \b({\bigg(} \def \b){\bigg)} \def \l{\left|} \def \r{\right|} \def\boxed#1{\bbox[10px,border:2px solid red]{#1}} \def\g#1{\color{green}{#1}} \def\oiint{\bigcirc\kern-1.4em\iint} \def \bc{\begin{cases}} \def \ec{\end{cases}}$$

Let $g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)-1}{\cos(x)}$.

I'm trying to prove that Newton's method applied to the equation $g(x)=0$ leads to the recurrence relation $$x_{x+1}=x_n+\cos(x_n).$$

Here's what I've done so far:

From the quotient rule, we have $$\begin{align}g'(x)&=\frac{\cos(x)\[\cos(x)\]-[\sin(x)-1][-\sin(x)]}{\cos^2(x)} \\ \ \\&=\sec(x)\[\sec(x)-\tan(x)\] \quad .\end{align}$$

Now, $$\begin{align} x_{n+1}&=x_n-\frac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)} \\ \ \\&=x_n-\[\frac{\{\frac{\sin(x_n)-1}{\cos(x_n)}\}}{\{\frac{\cos^2(x_n)-\sin^2(x_n)+\sin(x_n)}{\cos^2(x_n)}\}}\] \\ \ \\&=x_n-\[\frac{\cos^2(x_n)\{\sin(x_n)-1\}}{\cos(x_n)\{\cos^2(x_n)-\sin^2(x_n)+\sin(x_n)\}}\] \\ \ \\&=x_n-\[\frac{\cos(x_n)\sin(x_n)-\cos(x_n)}{\cos(2x_n)+\sin(x_n)}\] \\ \ \\&\neq x_n+\cos(x_n)\end{align}$$

Where am I going wrong? Is there some simple mistake that I'm making, or is everything wrong?

Comment: @alexqwz $(\cos x)^\prime=-\sin x$

Comment: @Elias The equation for $g'(x_n)$ is correct (I actually evaluated it on Wolfram, but it's not consistent with my working, so thanks for pointing that out), but where am I going wrong in the second part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to express $g'(x)$ in terms of $g(x)$. This would give you:$$g'(x)=\frac{1-\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=-\frac{g(x)}{\cos(x)}$$